# open programs with applescript

Tags: applescript

2 part question:

I'm simply trying to run programs using applescript from the terminal, so I tried:

```
$ osascript tell application "iTunes" to activate
```

and get the error:

```
osascript: tell: No such file or directory
```

Giving the full path to the program did not work either.  What am I missing?  The second part of the question is what I eventually want to use applescript for.  I would like to use it to open an application I built using py2app.  Can applescript open any mac app or just certain ones that are already compatible.

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

Try this. Notice you use "-e" when you are writing the command. Without "-e" you would give a path to an applescript to run. Also notice the string command must be in quotes.

```
osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\" to activate"
```

And if you have a multi-line applescript you use "-e" before each line like this...

```
osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\"" -e "activate" -e "end tell"
```

If you want to open an application just use the unix "open" command...

```
open "/path/to/application"
```

If you wanted to open an application using applescript and the "activate" command doesn't work (it should work for almost everything though) then tell the Finder to open it. Remember that applescript uses colon delimited paths...

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to open file \"path:to:application\""
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell which workspace to be opened on?

Comment: The big lesson I learned here is that single quotes won't work. You gotta use double quotes for the -e arguments.

Comment: @kakyo That is not correct. You **can** use single quotes, but if you do, you no longer need to escape the double quotes inside, which was previously necessary because they were inside double quotes. I mean you can use single quotes like this `osascript -e 'tell application "Kitty" to activate'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Okie. Thanks~

Answer (score 20):

In a bash shell (like in Terminal), you can send multiple lines to osascript by using a "here document".

```
osascript -e "tell application \"iTunes\"" -e "activate" -e "end tell"
```

becomes

```
osascript <<EOF
tell application "iTunes"
   activate
end tell
EOF
```

As an old-skool Unix hacker, I save these little snippets in my $HOME/bin directory and call them from the command line.  Still learning the particulars, though.

Alan

Answer (score 13):

an alternative to osascript:

```
open -a Calendar
```

close by:

```
pkill Calendar
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
do shell script "open /Applications/iTunes.app"
```

Comment: In the context of the original asker's question, this won't work, because the shell won't quote it either; AppleScript proper will see `do shell script open /Applications/iTunes.app` which results in exactly the same error in the question.

Answer (score 6):

you need to put single quotes around the tell:

osascript -e 'tell app "iTunes" to activate'

otherwise you're defining a variable when you run -e

Comment: Can you point to some documentation where this is explained? Looking through the man page for osascript I do not see this mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I'am new to script too.

I am confused to so I scan an essay named `AppleScript Language Guide`
and when I go through script commands items, I learn that if you want to activate an application in `mac os` with `applescript editor` you should type beneath code in your editor and then compile and run them! may this answer will help you, here's code:

```
// applescript editor code    

----------    

activate application "iTunes" line 1    

----------    

tell application "iTunes" to activate line 2
```